# How do I find the seed of my Minecraft World in Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have found a cool world and I'm trying to get the seed for it. Is there a command or setting for it?

Answer (score 0):

Java - /seed

Bedrock - Look at the pencil icon on the side of the world and find it in s